# Laravel MySql get attendance for players for match

Tags: mysql, laravel

Currently I am designing an app for Football Club which organises friendly match every weekend.

The system opens entry for players on Wednesday morning till Thursday 6PM. So players give their availability if they are available for match on that weekend or not and club organises accordingly.

I have 2 tables `matches` which saves match information like following.

```
id  | date | entry_open_time | entry_close_time | active | deleted | created | modified
```

Another table is `availabilities` table which saves `players` availability

```
id  | match_id  | player_id | is_available | deleted | created | modified
```

How can I calculate who is top of the leaderboard by attendance percentage for the year?

Currently I do the following.

1. Run 2 queries, one to get total number of matches organised in current year and second get total attendance count per user
2. Then I calculate percentage of attendance for each user looping through collection.
3. Then sort the collection.

Is there a better way to do this? May be get the results directly using mysql query?

Total Match count query

```
Match::where('active', true)->count();
```

Attendance by user

```
User::active()->withCount([
        'availabilities' => function ($query) {
            $query->available();
        },
    ])->orderBy('availabilities_count')->get()
```

Then I calculate the percentage for each user in collection

```
$availabilities->map(function ($item) use ($matchCount) {

        if ($item['availabilities_count'] && $matchCount) {
            $percentage = ($item['availabilities_count'] * 100) / $matchCount;
            $item['attendance'] = round($percentage,2);
        } else {
            $item['attendance'] = 0;
        }

        return $item;
    });
```

After that I sort the collection by attendance

```
$availability->sortBy('attendance');
```

Here is the sample [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06b5ee/1)

How can I get same result with mysql query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Mysql you can achieve your expected results as

```
select `u`.*, 
        ac.availabilities_count,
        mc.match_count,
        round((ac.availabilities_count/ mc.match_count) * 100,2) attendance
from `users` u
join (
  select user_id, count(*) availabilities_count
  from `availabilities`
  where `is_available` = 1
  group by user_id
) ac on `u`.`id` = `ac`.`user_id`
join (
  select count(*) match_count
  from matches
  -- where active = 1
) mc
order by `first_name`, `last_name`
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06b5ee/10)